# AWS RDS databases & SSIS

Tags: ssis, amazon-rds, aws

I have 2 AWS RDS databases (A & B) and need to create a datawarehouse with star scheme and slowly changing dimensions within AWS.

From a MS background it makes sense to create a SSIS package to run as a SQL job, which can collate the A & B databases and create dimensions and facts.

AWS RDS does not have SSIS support and I would therefore need to run an EC2 instance with SQL Server installed which then ran the SSIS package.

My questions is - is there any better way, assuming a heavy MS stack and AWS?

Comment: There are definitely other ETL tools, basic SQL being a definite option. The risk is that, in my experience, the vast majority of MS stack folks do not have experience with other tools... so if you go with another vendor option you're going to have skill set and hiring issues going forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use several ETL tools for this, it could be on premies, or cloud based, final decision always depends from cost, corporate standards and many other moments

good starting point as most close to Your request:

- Informatica Cloud -
  https://marketplace.informatica.com/mpresources/docs/Implementing_DWH_on_AWS_in_Hybrid_Env.pdf
- Talend Cloud - https://www.talend.com/products/integration-cloud
- Community version of Talend as well could be installed on any VPS and
  connect to cloud databases

Any tools and recommendations always depends from personal experience and of course on the market You can find more commercial and open source tools